# Why my canvas game code returns "undefined" from a module from constructor function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, module, game-engine, sprite-sheet

This is the constructor module I export from the sprite.js

```
export const Sprite = function(filename, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight,x){


this.img = new Image()
this.img.src = `./img/${filename}`
this.sx = sx
this.sy = sy
this.sWidth = sWidth
this.sHeight = sHeight
this.dx = dx
this.dy = dy
this.dWidth = dWidth
this.dHeight = dHeight


this.draw = function(x){
    return x.drawImage(this.img,this.sx,this.sy,this.sWidth,this.sHeight,this.dx,this.dy,this.dWidth,this.dHeight)
}
```

}

And than in the game.js I have like this:

```
  const ctx = game.getContext("2d");
  const player = new Sprite('player.png',10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,ctx)


  console.log(player.draw(ctx)) // undefined
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also undefined if I use class constructor...

Comment: Because `drawImage` returns `undefined`? What *precisely* is `undefined`?

Comment: is it possible to use parameter in this I use "x" and then when initialize the constructor I put "ctx" in the end?

Comment: I'm not sure what you just asked. You're asking if you can use a parameter inside the function that takes the parameter? Yes; that's the point of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Because [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) does not return a value.

What exactly are you expecting to be logged? `drawImage()` draws the supplied image to the canvas. The only output of the function is to modify the canvas - you can confirm if it worked by visual inspection.

Answer (score 0):

I forget to call the new player constructor function in the gameloop. Thank you for your comments.

```
   import {Sprite} from "./modules/sprite.mjs"
   const ctx = game.getContext("2d");

   const player = new Sprite('player.png',0,0,64,64,0,64,64,65)

   function draw(){
          player.draw(ctx)
   }


   function gameloop(){
          draw()
          requestAnimationFrame(gameloop)
    }
    gameloop()
```